# Custom compiler with maven

Tags: maven-2, coffeescript

I'm trying to make Maven2 to compile coffeescript to javascript. As far as I'm concerned there is no plugin which provides compiling coffeescript.

Is there a compiler-plugin for maven which can be parameterized with a compiler (for any programming language)?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a compiler-plugin for maven which can be parameterized with a compiler (for any programming language)?

This is actually the case of the Maven Compiler Plugin, see [Using Non-Javac Compilers](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/non-javac-compilers.html). So one could imagine providing a pluggable compiler implementation to compile coffeescript.

Comment: +1. Btw, what do you think of transforming the `maven-2` tag to just `maven`? Since there is now maven 3, it will be better, I think. Perhaps it would require retagging of some maven-1 specific questions to `maven-1`, though. (I know this is a discussion for meta, I will start it if you agree, since your are the top mavener ;) )

Comment: @Bozho I don't know, it's a tough question. The fact is that there are Maven 1 specific questions, there will be Maven 3 specific questions and there is Maven 2 in between. So having different tags makes sense IMO. My suggestion would be to move this idea on Meta, that's where such a retag must be discussed anyway.

Comment: @Bozho Oh, the comment changed. I think an explicit tag for `maven-1` would be nice. But what would be the added value of renaming `maven-2` in `maven`? And what would you suggest for `maven-3` then?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67222/to-retag-or-not-to-retag-maven-questions see here

Comment: @Pascal perfect answer, just what I would have said (+1), but I might've also added a GMaven solution :-)

Answer (score 3):

coffeescript-maven-plugin

https://github.com/iron9light/coffeescript-maven-plugin